# DBus signal receivers are never called

Tags: python, dbus

In my code I register to receive signals when USB devices are inserted.

```
def registerSignals(self):
    for signal, callback, bus, interface in (('InterfacesAdded', self.onUSBInterfaceAdded, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2', 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'),
                                            ('InterfacesRemoved', self.onUSBInterfaceRemoved, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2', 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'),
                                            ('PropertiesChanged', self.onUSBMountPropertiesChanged, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2', 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')):
        print(self.__bus.add_signal_receiver(callback,
                                        bus_name=bus,
                                        signal_name=signal,
                                        dbus_interface=interface))
                                       
def onUSBInterfaceAdded(self, path, interfaces):
    print(path)
    print(interfaces)

def onUSBInterfaceRemoved(self, path, interfaces):
    print(path)
    print(interfaces)

def onUSBMountPropertiesChanged(self, interface, properties, invalidated, path):
    print(path)
    print(interfaces)
```

Now, when I run this code, I get *no* signals. The problem is that when I run `dbus-monitor --system` in the CLI, I do see the messages when I insert a USB device. Any idea how to debug this? Or what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What D-Bus bindings are you using?

I find the [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) bindings to be far easier to work with in Python. For example:

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydbus
>>> udisk2 = pydbus.SystemBus().get('.UDisks2')
>>> udisk2.on <-tab complete pressed->
udisk2.onInterfacesAdded    udisk2.onInterfacesRemoved  udisk2.onPropertiesChanged  
>>> udisk2.onInterfacesAdded = print
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to setup the eventloop (converted your example to plain functions):

```py
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from gi.repository import GLib


def registerSignals():
    for signal, callback, bus, interface in (('InterfacesAdded', onUSBInterfaceAdded, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2', 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'),
                                             ('InterfacesRemoved', onUSBInterfaceRemoved, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2', 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'),
                                             ('PropertiesChanged', onUSBMountPropertiesChanged, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2', 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')):
        print(dbus.SystemBus().add_signal_receiver(callback,
                                                   bus_name=bus,
                                                   signal_name=signal,
                                                   dbus_interface=interface))


def onUSBInterfaceAdded(path, interfaces):
    print(path)
    print(interfaces)


def onUSBInterfaceRemoved(path, interfaces):
    print(path)
    print(interfaces)


def onUSBMountPropertiesChanged(interface, properties, invalidated, path):
    print(path)
    print(interfaces)


DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
registerSignals()
GLib.MainLoop().run()
```